# BSOD when connecting to wifi

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, bsod

I did not have any problem connecting to wifi at all. However, I went to a public library, and when I try to connect with the library's wifi, automatically I get a Blue Screen of Death. It didn't happened anywhere else, but it happens everytime I try to connect with that wifi. However, other people can connect normally. Why is that?

Extra info:

I have windows 8, and my computer is a toshiba Sattellite C855-22M.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Without further information about said BSOD (numbers, filenames), we can’t help you.

Comment: copy the folder **C:\windows\minidump** to the desktop, zip the folder, upload the zip to a cloud service and post a link here.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess - I would say it was a corruption in your wireless drivers which caused an unhandled exception when joining a network with a name of a certain length or a certain BSSID... but I cannto comment for sure.

Try reinstalling your wireless drivers and see if it helps.

Without more specific error information (bluescreen ID, file name or erroring module name, error description text etc), we will be unable to help further.

As a general rule - try a chkdsk on the off chance it was a freak occurance and was actually your drive.  Also, try system restore to a previous known working time.  If you have introduced any new updates, software of hardware to your system - try removing them and attempting again incase there is a conflict... but this is just general troubleshooting advice, not aimed at your particular problem.